# using regexps in C

Tags: c, regex, string

So I have an IP address lets say like this: 100.50.23.56

I want to be able to extract the 100, 50, 23, 56, and add them all together and store that in a new variable.

The ip address comes in as a string.

So I'm assuming I have to use regular expressions. But I am not sure how to do that.

Can someone give me a quick example?

Thanks.

Comment: don't use regular expressions here

Comment: use inet_aton or inet_addr functions to do this

Comment: While for general work using the address parsing functions makes sense, it is not clear that it is appropriate here.  In particular, extracting the 4 components of the dotted-decimal notation from the 4-byte IPv4 address is not as obvious as processing the multi-dotted string as a series of integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use a steamroller to crack a walnut, it is usually regarded as overkill to do so. Ditto with a regular expression for the job at hand. You could use [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) fairly effectively (once per set of digits). You could use [`sscanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sscanf.html) pretty effectively, too.

```
int ip[4];
if (sscanf("100.50.23.56", "%d.%d.%d.%d", &ip[0], &ip[1], &ip[2], &ip[3]) != 4)
    ...report problem and do not continue...
int sum = ip[0] + ip[1] + ip[2] + ip[3];
```

You could use 4 separate variables instead of an array; this code doesn't benefit much (if at all) from using an array.

```
char *end;
char *begin = "100.50.23.56";
int sum = 0;
long part;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (((part = strtol(begin, &end, 10)) == 0 && begin == end) ||
        (part < 0 || part > 255))
        ...report problem and return...
    sum += part;
    if (*end != '\0')
        end++;
    begin = end;
}
```

<sup>***Warning***: *untested code.*</sup>

Note that both these solutions permit spaces before the numbers, and don't care about trailing garbage, so they'd both parse `" 100.  50.   23.    56 and counting"`.  Tightening the code to handle such malformed IPv4 addresses is perfectly feasible, but not as simple as the code shown.

Also note that if you were trying to generate an IP address for use with the networking functions, you'd do better with the functions specifically for converting strings to IP addresses.  However, extracting the components of the IPv4 address is slightly messy (bit masking and shifting — not all that hard), which is why I chose not to do it here.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers. I'm not sure why you all down voted my question as that wasn't necessary but, what else should I expect from SO? Regardless, I thank you all for these informative answers, as expected on SO :)

Comment: Yes indeed, the down votes and the closing of questions are the weakiest points of SO.  For example, I have often see perfectly valid questions to be closed just because the people didn't really understood them and this happen quite frequently because the people will close question outside of their main field of competence.  For example, someone who know about C++ but not really about Java or Android will often close a question on Java or Android; trying to show that he/she knows it all.

Comment: @SylvainL What nonsense are you talking about? `trying to show that he/she knows it all.` how do you know that? This question could be downvoted merely because the OP didn't provide any code/attempt to solve his problem. Now there's a hole in the closing system. SO/SE is just too nice and didn't accept close reasons like `we are not a free coding service, try to solve your problem by writing code, if you get stuck post it here`. That's why some people close it as "unclear" or "too broad" or whatever close reason remotely close to it.

Comment: While there are some questions that have been downvoted for the reasons that you have mentionned, a lot of perfectly valid questions are for what to seem no valid reason at all.  In fact, the original question here is exactly in that case and I have often seen much more questionable downvoting. In fact, I have often see downvoting made by people with little or no knowledge at all for the field.  Anyone following the Android tag have seen a lot of perfectly valid (and often complex) questions downvoted or even closed by people who have practically never answered a good question on Android.

Comment: At a minimum, the downvoting and closing rights should be reserved to people with a minimum number of points in the field of question.  For example, it shouldn't be sufficient to have an overall of 3000 points to close a question on Android; instead, you should have 3000 points directed associated with questions on Android to have such a right.  (And even then, it's incredible the amount of energy spent on downvoting and closing questions. Instead, this energy should be spent on answering questions; which is much more usefull.

Answer (score 0):

Without error-checking, this only needs a handful of lines of code to do. Error-checking will add a few more, but it's still simple enough not to need any heavy-weight machinery like regular expressions.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void parse_ip(unsigned char ip[4], const char *s) {
    memset(ip, 0, 4);
    for (; *s; s++) {
        if (*s == '.') ip++;
        else *ip = *ip * 10 + *s - '0';
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    unsigned char ip[4];
    parse_ip(ip, "100.50.23.56");
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3]);
    return 0;
}
```